How can I troubleshoot my Windows SSD that suddenly won't boot anymore?
I have a setup with two drives, a SSD and a HDD, both with Windows 10 installed. I always boot from SSD but today I left my PC on as usual and when I came back I noticed it was displaying my old HDD desktop.
I rebooted the machine and found out that even though the SSD is detected by BIOS as a boot option and I can access it's files by booting from HDD, it won't boot anymore.
By this I figure this is probably a Windows issue and that I should reinstall it on the SSD. But before trying that I'd like to know:
1 - Is my assumption correct? What else should I check before reaching a conclusion?
2 - If I'm right, what could've caused this issue? Faulty Windows update? Sudden power outage? My cat pressed some forbidden key combination while I was away? Virus? How can Windows suddenly stop working and the machine reboot itself after it?

When you unplug the HDD and try to boot, what does it say? When booting from the HDD can you access the SSH the files seems intact?
